# jQuery Accordion Menu - Keep menu open when sub item is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, accordion

I would like to keep my menu open when I am on a page in the sub navigation. This way it will allow the user to tell much more easily where they are on the site. How can I accomplish this with the code I have? Thanks for any feedback.

jQuery:

```
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {

  var checkElement = $(this).next();

  $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('active'); 

  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
    checkElement.slideUp('normal', function() {
        menuHeight();
    });
  }
  if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
    $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal', function() {
        menuHeight();
    });
    checkElement.slideDown('normal', function() {
        menuHeight();
    });
  }

  if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false; 
  }

});
```

HTML (sample):

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
        <li id="home"><a href='/index'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li id="landscaping-overview"><a href='/landscaping/landscaping-overview'><span>Landscaping</span></a>
            <ul>
            <li id="landscaping-planters"><a href='/landscaping/planters'><span>Planters</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-walls"><a href='/landscaping/walls'><span>Walls</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-stone-work"><a href='/landscaping/stone-work'><span>Stone Work</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-walkways"><a href='/landscaping/walkways'><span>Walkways</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-stairways"><a href='/landscaping/stairways'><span>Stairways</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-steps"><a href='/landscaping/steps'><span>Steps</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-water-falls"><a href='/landscaping/water-falls'><span>Water Falls</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-ponds"><a href='/landscaping/ponds'><span>Ponds</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-creek-beds"><a href='/landscaping/creek-beds'><span>Creek Beds</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-pondless-water-features"><a href='/landscaping/pondless-water-features'><span>Pondless Water Features</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-enhancement-lighting"><a href='/landscaping/enhancement-lighting'><span>Enhancement Lighting</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-patios"><a href='/landscaping/patios'><span>Patios</span></a></li>
            <li id="landscaping-fireplaces"><a href='/landscaping/fireplaces'><span>Fireplaces</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a reason you are using js instead of a css/css3 menu instead?  from what I can see that the css menu would solve most of your problems alone with added the animations for browsers supporting css3.

Comment: Most menus, on even the most complex examples have a css fall back, and i would recommend trying that.  Do you have a fiddle with a example of the menu with the applied css?